# Checkout is not available whilst your cart is empty

Tags: woocommerce, payment, checkout, endpoint

My WooCommerce website is not redirecting to order received page (“order-received“) after completing the payment. It used to show customer their order details (default template from WooCommerce) after completing the payment where they can print the tax invoice if needed.

Not sure why it doesn’t automatically redirect now. I have tested both payment via, PayPal and Stripe.

When a customer pays via stripe (Debit/Credit card) it redirects to cart page and says “Checkout is not available whilst your cart is empty”. So they end up trying again, and in process duplicating the order.

I am using WooCommerce Stripe Gateway and WooCommerce PayPal Payments.

The website is currently running WooCommerce version 7.5.1 and using official WooCommerce Storefront theme, version 4.1.3, php version 8.1.16, WordPress version 6.2.

Haven’t made any changes to the theme recently.

Would really appreciate your help to fix this issue.

Thank you.

I have tired reinstalling Stripe plugin as well as clearing cache.